# File disappears after upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, upload, cypress

Requirement:

Add file  and Upload.

I have added file on the fixtures folder.

file name = pdf1.pdf

Code:

```
cy.wait(10000)
    cy.fixture('pdf1.pdf').then(fileContent => {
    cy.get('#Shipment_PaperlessFile').attachFile ({

      fileContent: fileContent.toString(),
      fileName: 'pdf1.pdf',
      mimeType: 'text/pdf'

    })
  })
```

When I ran the code, the file is added.

[image]

But after this I have to click on the Create button for the file to get uploaded. But after I click on the submit button (Create), then the file that was added disappears and shows the following:

"Please upload pdf file."

[image]

Comment: You've to stay on the same page, don't submit the form.

Comment: Actually, the feature tells to click on the submit button to get the file uploaded.

Comment: A form is a link, when submitted, it will always load a new page (or reload the current page, if there's no `action` property defined).

Comment: When I try manually, then the file gets uploaded, but in automation there's  this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just used the following : 
cy.get('#Shipment_PaperlessFile').attachFile ('pdf1.pdf')

and it worked.